# Python 2.7 Logger not printing **args

Tags: python-2.7, logging

Logger.error is not printing args when I do:

`models.LOGGER.error('ji', {'error_msg':'msg'})`

I have a hunch that it is my logging.conf file. According to documentation https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

```
[loggers]
keys=root, appLogger, sentryLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=stdFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_appLogger]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=appLogger
propagate=0

[logger_sentryLogger]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=sentryLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=stdFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)


[formatter_stdFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s (%(asctime)s; %(filename)s:%(lineno)d)
datefmt=
```

Comment: You did not specify what you expected the logged output to look like.

Comment: I thought that formatter does that. Can you please give and example of how I could have done it @StephenRauch. Thanks

Comment: As I asked the first time, what do you expect the log to look like?

Comment: @StephenRauch `TravolutionaryException: {'error_msg':'msg'}`. Thanks for your help